# Existe alguna manera de crear una lista por cada elemento de otra lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Supongamos que tengo una lista asi:

```
l=[20,30,40]
```

Cómo hago para crear 3 listas así:

```
l1=[2,0]
l2=[3,0]
l3=[4,0]
```

PD:Se me ocurrió esta pregunta para encontrar como multiplicar cada digito de un número en una lista. Por ejemplo a partir de la lista [22,23,24] me gustaria obtener [4,6,8]. Si existe una manera más eficiente de resolver esto me sería util la explicación, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l=[20,30,40]
r = [[int(c) for c in str(e)] for e in l]
print(r)
```

```
[[2, 0], [3, 0], [4, 0]]
```

Como ves, el truco es pasar cada elemento (`e`) de la lista `l` a string, para después iterar por cada uno de los caracteres (`c`) de ese string y convertirlo a `int`. La sintaxis de *list comprehensions* permite expresar todo ello en una sola línea. Si prefieres más la sintaxis de bucles sería así (mucho más farragosa en mi opinión):

```
r = []
for e in l:
  aux = []
  for c in str(e):
    aux.append(int(c))
  r.append(aux)
print(r)
```

#### El producto

Y respondiendo a tu "verdadera" pregunta, calcular el producto de los dígitos de cada número, tenemos dos enfoques:

1. Usar programación funcional para operar sobre cada elemento de la lista `r` (que es a su vez una sub-lista), reduciendo la sub-lista a un solo dato (haciendo uso de `functools.reduce()`, y aplicando el operador de multiplicación a todos ellos).
2. Usar un bucle for para lo mismo.

La programación funcional oculta los bucles, permitiendo programas más cortos, pero en ocasiones más difíciles de leer. En el caso de la función `functools.reduce()` es uno de esos casos en los que, por hacer el programa más compacto, pierde legibilidad (de hecho el propio Guido, creador de python, lo desaconseja). Sería así:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

l = [123, 35, 11111]
r = [[int(c) for c in str(n)] for n in l]
p = [reduce(mul, sublist) for sublist in r]
print(p)
```

```
[6, 15, 1]
```

En este caso una solución con bucles es, para mi gusto, más legible:

```
l = [123, 35, 11111]
for e in l:
  product = 1
  for digit in str(e):
    product *= int(digit)
  print(product)
```

```
6
15
1
```

Observa que, tanto la versión funcional como la de bucles, sirven para datos de cualquier longitud.

Answer (score 1):

```
lista = [22, 23, 24]
numIzq = []
numDer = []

# Calcula el digito de la izquierda (Solo menores a 100)
for i in range(len(lista)):
    numIzq.insert(i, lista[i] * 0.1)
    numIzq[i] = int(numIzq[i] // 1)
print(numIzq)

# Calcula el digito de la derecha (solo menores a 100)
for k in range(len(lista)):
    numDer.insert(k, numIzq[k] * 10)
    numDer[k] = lista[k] - numDer[k]
print(numDer)

# Sobreescribo la lista inicial con el culculo entre listas izq y der
for j in range(len(lista)):
    lista[j] = numIzq[j] * numDer[j]
print(lista)
```

Solo lo hice para números menores a 100. Si entiendes la logica (Y mi manera de codificar) tranquilamente puedes hacerlo para cualquiera.
PD: Ve poniendo print() en todos los lugares que podrían arrojar un resultado. De esta forma, podrás visualizar cada uno y entender el proceso